# how to import arch correctly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, arch

I install arch4.8.1, but when I import it ,there is an error

I have tried reinstalling, but this has no effect

```
from arch.unitroot import ADF
```

Then it has a error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-41aa8ae22fe2> in <module>
----> 1 from arch.unitroot import ADF

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\arch\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from arch._version import get_versions
----> 2 from arch.univariate.mean import arch_model
      3 from arch.utility import test
      4
      5 __version__ = get_versions()['version']

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\arch\univariate\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from arch.univariate.distribution import (Distribution, GeneralizedError,
      4                                           Normal, SkewStudent, StudentsT)
----> 5 from arch.univariate.mean import (ARX, HARX, LS, ConstantMean, ZeroMean,
      6                                   arch_model)
      7 from arch.univariate.volatility import (ARCH, EGARCH, FIGARCH, GARCH, HARCH,

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\arch\univariate\mean.py in <module>
     15 from statsmodels.tsa.tsatools import lagmat
     16
---> 17 from arch.univariate.base import (ARCHModel, ARCHModelForecast,
     18                                   ARCHModelResult, implicit_constant)
     19 from arch.univariate.distribution import (GeneralizedError, Normal,

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\arch\univariate\base.py in <module>
     23
     24 from arch.univariate.distribution import Distribution, Normal
---> 25 from arch.univariate.volatility import ConstantVariance, VolatilityProcess
     26 from arch.utility.array import AbstractDocStringInheritor, ensure1d
     27 from arch.utility.exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, StartingValueWarning,

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\arch\univariate\volatility.py in <module>
     21
     22 try:
---> 23     from arch.univariate.recursions import (garch_recursion, harch_recursion,
     24                                             egarch_recursion, midas_recursion,
     25                                             figarch_weights, figarch_recursion)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\arch\univariate\recursions.cp36-win_amd64.pyd in init arch.univariate.recursions()

AttributeError: type object 'arch.univariate.recursions.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by packages compiled by different versions of Cython. My solution is to roll back to an old version of “arch”. Version 4.6.0 works perfectly for me. Good luck for you.